# svmult doesn't play well with babel

Tags: sv-classes

MWE using svmult class from https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20568/data/v8

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{introduction}

Foo Bar

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\end{document}
```

When compiled via *pdflatexmk* gives me the following error:

```
./authorsample.aux:5: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \newlabel{introduction}{{1}{1}}[
                                    None]
```

*authorsample.aux* is

```
\relax 
\bibstyle{spbasic}
\immediate\closeout\minitoc
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{introduction}{{1}{1}}[None]
```

How can I use *svmult* with babel?

Comment: the class loads ntheorem with thref option, and this only works if it is loaded after babel (see the ntheorem docu). So ask the class maintainer what to do.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any advice on identifying the class maintainer?

Comment: well you downloaded a large zip. So look in the various files, or check their website. Btw: the class redefines nearly all latex structures including a number of internal commands. So you should use it only if it really fits, it would be difficult to adapt or correct.

Comment: I have grep'ed all files in that ZIP for e-mail addresses. The only ones in there are `meier@tu.edu`, `name@email.addres` and `smith@smith.edu`. All examples. I did download an older version from https://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics?SGWID=0-40292-2-122598-0 and found `texhelp@springer.de`. I'll reach out now. Wish me luck :D

Comment: well if everything fails you can always edit the class. But if someone asked you to use it, they should imho also offer support for it.

Comment: Agreed. Hoping for the best. Thanks @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find is to edit the class by removing the *ntheorem* package I do not require, as suggested in comments.

```
diff --git a/svmult.cls b/svmult.cls
index 2c39e97..62287b8 100644
--- a/svmult.cls  
+++ b/svmult.cls  
@@ -2460,13 +2460,13 @@ to\z@{\kern0.55\wd0\vrule\@height0.45\ht0\hss}\box0}}}}
 
                         %%%SOPHIE TEMPLATE END%%%
 
-\usepackage[thmmarks,thref]{ntheorem} 
-\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
-\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\itshape}
-\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
-\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
-\newtheorem{proof}{Proof} 
-\gdef\NoneSymbol{}
+%\usepackage[thmmarks,thref]{ntheorem}
+%\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
+%\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\itshape}
+%\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
+%\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
+%\newtheorem{proof}{Proof} 
+%\gdef\NoneSymbol{}
 
 \endinput
 %end of file svmult.cls
```